# slf4j.Marker incompatible types

Tags: java, slf4j

I have been using slf4j this way and all is fine:

```
LOGGER.info("classification: {} {} {}", classification, question, id);
```

But suddenly I am not aware of any changes that is causing this error messages:

```
Error:(50, 25) java: incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to org.slf4j.Marker
```

In command line, 'mvn clean install' compiles fine. But in IntelliJ when I tried to start an application, the error message above pops up.

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you hit other overrides of the LOGGER.info:

```
void info(Marker marker,
        String format,
        Object... arguments)
This method is similar to info(String, Object...) method except that the marker data is also taken into consideration.
```

https://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/Logger.html#info(org.slf4j.Marker,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)

Basic adapters like Log4jLoggerAdapater extend MarkerIgnoringBase. MarkerIgnoringBase doesn't have Marker overrides. Seems that IntelliJ started to use adapter that is not extending MarkerIgnoringBase.

Comment: I have lots of LOGGER.info() usages, suddenly today all reported this error. The question is why it now calls the info(Marker, ...) version?

Comment: what are the types of classification, question, id? Are all of them String or something else?

Comment: Yes. all are Java strings.

Comment: Can you break point and check the logger implementation. Basic adapters like Log4jLoggerAdapater extend MarkerIgnoringBase. MarkerIgnoringBase doesn't have Marker overrides. Seems that IntelliJ started to use adapter that is not extending MarkerIgnoringBase.

Comment: I am glad for you :)